# Merge 2 dataframes with priority (A over B if specific columns match)

Tags: pandas, merge

I have a dataframe A:

```
orderid | productnumber | productcount | productname    | productsize | deliverydate | source 
1       | 111           | 11           | "big fridge"   | 100x200x300 | 2020-11-01   | "A"
1       | 222           | 22           | "big fridge"   | 100x200x300 | 2020-11-11   | "A"
1       | 333           | 33           | "small fridge" | 100x200x300 | 2020-11-12   | "A"
```

And dataframe B:

```
orderid | productnumber | productcount | productname    | productsize | deliverydate | transport | source 
1       | 111           | 13           | "big fridge"   | 100x200x300 | 2020-11-03   | "ship"    | "B"
1       | 222           | 22           | "big fridge"   | 100x200x300 | 2020-11-11   | "ship"    | "B"
```

A is older, B is more up2date for specific columns and contains more informations/columns but may not contain the newest stuff/rows.

So if **"orderid" + "productnumber"** match, B has priority over A and should therefore replace rows from A when both are merged.

End result should be:

```
orderid | productnumber | productcount | productname    | productsize | deliverydate | transport | source 
1       | 111           | 13           | "big fridge"   | 100x200x300 | 2020-11-03   | "ship"    | "B"
1       | 222           | 22           | "big fridge"   | 100x200x300 | 2020-11-11   | "ship"    | "B"
1       | 333           | 33           | "small fridge" | 100x200x300 | 2020-11-12   |           | "A"
```

How can I do this easily with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) dataframes, then perform [`dataframe.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). Depending on precedence of A and B, change `keep` value to "last" and "first". Depending on your pandas version, you may need to [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) instead of using `ignore_index` param.

```
merged_df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
# merged_df.sort_values(["source"], inplace=True)
merged_df.drop_duplicates(["orderid", "productnumber"], keep="last", inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
```